# grep lines that contain 1 character followed by another character

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm working on my assignment and I've been stuck on this question, and I've tried looking for a solution online and my textbook.

The question is:

> List all the lines in the `f3.txt` file that contain words with a character `b` not followed by a character `e`.

I'm aware you can do `grep -i 'b'` to find the lines that contain the letter `b`, but how can I make it so that it only shows the lines that contain `b` but not followed by the character `e`?

Comment: Check this [grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions). I also strongly recommend checking this [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to better understand regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll check the suggested links and report back.

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can go for the following two solutions:

```
grep -ie 'b[^e]' input_file.txt
```

or

```
grep -ie 'b.' input_file.txt | grep -vi 'be'
```

**The first one does use regex:**

- `'b[^e]'` means `b followed by any symbol that is not e`
- `-i` is to ignore case, with this option lines containing `B` or `b` that are not directly followed by `e` or `E` will be accepted

**The second solution calls grep twice:**

- the first time you look for patterns that contains b only to select those lines
- the resulting lines are filtered by the second grep using `-v` to reject lines containing `be`
- both grep are ignoring the case by using `-i`
- if `b` must **absolutely** be followed by another character then use `b.` (regex meaning `b` followed by any other char) otherwise if you want to also accept lines where `b` is not followed by any other character at all you can just use `b` in the first grep call instead of `b.`.

  ```
  grep -ie 'b' input_file.txt | grep -vi 'be'
  ```

**input:**

```
BEBE
bebe
toto
abc
bobo
```

**result:**

```
abc
bobo
```

Comment: By the way, your second solution is identical to mine with 7 minutes delay

Comment: It's was not clear for me if `b` had to be followed by a character or if it was ok for it to be at the end of line. Anyway for something so trivial I don't need to peek on you dude! :-) And I might be typing too slowly...

Answer (score 2):

This will find a "b" that is not followed by "e":

```
$ echo "one be
two
bring
brought" | egrep 'b[^e]'
```

Or if perl is available but egrep is not:

```
$ echo "one be
two
bring
brought" | perl -ne 'print if /b[^e]/;'
```

And if you want to find lines with "b" not followed by "e" but *no* words that contain "be" (using the *\w* perl metacharacter to catch another character after the b), and avoiding any words that end with b:

```
$ echo "lab
bribe
two
bring
brought" | perl -ne 'print if /b\w/ && ! /be/'
```

So the final call would:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /b\w/ && ! /be/' f3.txt
```

Comment: No need for `egrep`.

Comment: Test it with the word `bribe`

Comment: yes, but from what he/she said above was words that contained b not followed by e.  Bribe contains a "b" not followed by an "e", and one "b" that is followed by an "e".

Comment: Since in `bribe` we have a `b` followed by `e` if i was this guy's teacher i would request `bribe` to be excluded from the results...

Comment: OK, with a little change above, avoiding the *bribe* ;-)

Comment: @ProvenSupreme if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: Another "gray" word: Should `lab` be matched? Your perl solution matches `lab`.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou at this point the question is too vague to decide what should be matched and what should not.

Comment: @PesaThe I know you didn't answer the question, but if a question is "too vague", people should ask clarifying questions in comments and/or vote to close as "unclear" instead of answering.

Answer (score 1):

Exluding "edge" words that may exist and break the exercise, like `lab` , `bribe` and `bob`:

```
$ a="one                      
two
lab
bake
bob
aberon
bee
bell
bribe
bright
eee" 

$ echo "$a" |grep -v 'be' |grep 'b.'
bake
bob
bright
```

Comment: your solution does take into account the case try `BOB`, `BEBE`, ... anyway I will vote it up

Comment: Indeed. To ignore the case if requested we need the `-i` grep switch.